# Win 10: Monitor won't stay asleep for long

Tags: windows-10, display, sleep, wake-up

I have 2 Windows 10 units:

- Dell XPS 8900 with Dell 24" Monitor. Win 10 Home
- Dell Latitude 7490. Win 10 Pro LTS

Units both are set to have monitors sleep after 10mins. Both will do that, but both seem wake up after ~5-10 mins or so, then go back to sleep, and repeat.

It's not a system sleep - that works as expected. There isn't any logging or utilities to see why these monitors sleep/wake. Thinking its possibly very small mouse movements - but I live on a busy road near rail and even when something big goes by, it doesn't wake. Further the laptop only has  the trackpad attached so probably not mouse related.

Anyone solve something similar, having a 24" monitor light up your home randomly all night is troublesome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just starting having the same issue on a new HP tower with 2 monitors. The tower has two video ports, one is a VGA, the other is an HDMI. There is no problem with the HDMI, but when a monitor is connected to the VGA and the preset time has come for the monitors to sleep, after 30 - 60 seconds the 'device connected/disconnected' audio alert sounds. The alerts will sound every 60 seconds from then on, and the monitors will wake up every few cycles.

After several unsuccessful calls to HP, upgrading to latest (1903) windows version, driver updates, etc. and still no fix, I came up with my own solution. Instead of having different time settings for the display sleep and computer sleep modes, I set them to the exact same time. This way once the displays turn off, the computer goes to sleep as well and is not able to turn them back on or generate the alerts.

Comment: I solved (mitigated) on my desktop more or less accidentally by getting a new mouse w/pad. It looks like the Dell 4-level sensitively mouse was causing the wake ups (even on “dull” setting). Got a new mouse and pad and the issue stopped. The Latitude  still does it so looks like different causes.